# Removing old files after grunt usemin with filerev

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, minify, grunt-usemin

I am using usemin to generate my JS and CSS files - all in a pretty standard way.

Only problem I am having is that I would like to remove old compiled files from my dist.

My grunt config is:

```
grunt.registerTask('build',['jshint','copy','html2js:main','useminPrepare','concat:generated','cssmin:generated','uglify:generated','filerev','usemin','html2js:embed','clean:build']);
grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        default: {},            
        useminPrepare: {
            html: 'index.html',
            options: {
                dest: 'dist',
                flow: {
                    steps: {
                        nominjs: ['concat'],
                        js: ['concat','uglifyjs'],
                        css: ['concat','cssmin']
                    },
                    post: {}
                }
            }
        },
        filerev: {
            options: {
                encoding: 'utf8',
                algorithm: 'md5',
                length: 8
            },
            source: {
                files: [{
                    src: [
                        'dist/assets/css/ipp-styles.min.css',
                        'dist/scripts/ipp-scripts.min.js',
                        'dist/scripts/ipp-libs.js',
                        'dist/scripts/ipp-templates.min.js'
                    ]
                }]
            }
        },
        usemin: {
            html:['dist/index.html'],
            options: {
                blockReplacements: {
                    nominjs: function(block){
                        return '<script src="'+block.dest+'"></script>';
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        clean: {
            build: ['.tmp']
        },
        copy: {  
            html: {
                files: [
                    {expand:true, src:['index.html'], dest: 'dist'},
                    {expand:true, src:['.htaccess'], dest: 'dist'}                        
                ]
            },
            assets: {
                files: [
                    {expand:true, src:['assets/images/**','assets/fonts/**','assets/js/**'], dest: 'dist'}
                ]
            },
            libs: {
                files: [
                    {expand:true, src:['libs/forge.min.js'], dest: 'dist'},
                ]
            },
            config: {
                files: [
                    {expand:true, src:['config/config_diff.js'], dest:'dist', rename: function(dest,src){
                        return dest + '/' + src.replace(/\.js$/,"_sample.js");
                    }},
                ]
            }                
        },
        jshint: {
            options: {
                force: true,
                esnext: true
            },
            all: [
                'config/*.js',
                'scripts/**/*.js',
                '!scripts/ipp-scripts*'
            ]
        },
        uglify: {
            options: {
                compress: {
                    drop_console: true
                }
            }
        },            
        html2js: {
            main: {
                options: {
                    base:''
                },
                src: ['views/**/*.html'],
                dest: 'dist/scripts/templates.js'
            }
        }
    });
```

Nothing too special about it I would say. Everything works great, only "problem" I am having is that after couple of builds I end up with this:

[image]

And then I have to go and **manually** remove old files.

Is there a way to remove them during grunt run ? I could remove "ipp-scripts.min*" after the run, but I need to exclude the one that is currently used.

Comment: You should build into a new folder that's separate from your source. Then you can just delete that folder.

Comment: @srlm What do you mean? Every time building to different folder? doesnt make much sense. At the end of the day, you have your **dist** folder and you want to have only one version of minified file there

Answer (score 0):

I guess I wasn't thinking straight when setting this up. The solution was much easier than I expected.

Simply:

```
clean: {
            dist: [
                'dist/assets/css/ipp-styles.min*',
                'dist/scripts/ipp-scripts.min*',
                'dist/scripts/ipp-libs.min*',
                'dist/scripts/ipp-templates.min*'
            ]
        },
```

and run this as a first task in build.

This will remove all compiled files first and then compile new ones.

I think what confused me is that I thought if I dont have the last compiled, filerev is gonna mark always latest file with new stamp and therefore it will force re-load on user browsers. But actually the stamp added to file is somehow counted (probably) from the content sum, so even if you delete the file first and dont change anything file with same name is generated.

I realize this is still not the ultimate solution on how to remove all other files but the one that is included in index, so not gonna accept my own answer.